# How to use os.execve in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, os.execl

I just started learning Python today and couldn't find a good example online to help me understand `os.execve(path, args, env)` properly.

How do I use this method (`os.execve`) to achieve the following task in Python 3.4?
Execute an external command (this command is not some windows command like mkdir, cd... It's a custom command), its location is `C:\blah` and it takes 5 command line arguments.

Any simpler example of using this command would be much appreciated.

Comment: The os.exec* function will stop your program from executing. Is that really what you want?

Comment: fine how to exexute the external command without stopping my program ?

Comment: "I just started learning Python today and couldn't find a good example online to help me understand `os.execve(path, args, env)` properly.". Python has a superb online documentation, if you can find it, you are doing something wrong... [Link to os.execve documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.execve)

Comment: @KurzedMetal The os.exec* has a horrible documentation. Which type should the `args` be? What should be the `env`? If the documentation bothered to give an example, perhaps I wouldn't be banging the wall with an `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'keys'` error right now.

Comment: UPD. Ok, the following is a working example to execute a python script from python: `os.execv('./myscript.py', ['any_arbitrary_tag', '--my-argument', '--another-argument 42'])`
The `env` means the PATH variable of current environment and can be retrieved by `os.environ.get('PATH')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use subprocess:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.check_call(["C:\my program.exe", "all", "my", "args"])
```

os.exec* replaces the current program with another one. It has is uses, but its usually not what you want.

Note that there are several variants here:

1. `call` just calls the program.
2. `check_call` calls the program and throws an exception if it fails.
3. `check_output` calls the program, throws an exception if it fails, and returns the output of the program.

More advanced use cases can be handled by `subprocess.Popen` objects.

Comment: how would this work for a command like " login -u john -ac regular -p password" where login is login.exe ,the command

Comment: `subprocess.call(["login", "-u", "john", "-ac", "regular", "-p", "password"])`. (You may need to pass the full path to login)

Comment: @DhiwakarRavikumar, yes.

Comment: that was stupid to ask I should've tried first. it works on windows as well, is there any simpler way to write this as opposed to the CSV style ? its something that could be improved :)

Comment: @DhiwakarRavikumar, what do you mean by "csv" style?

Comment: I have some commmands that have quite a few arguments and this can get pretty tedious. CSV is Comma Separated Value

Comment: @DhiwakarRavikumar, there are alternatives, look at the subprocess documentation. But passing lists is the recommended way.

Comment: The best way to pass multiple arguments is to use [shlex](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shlex.html): `subprocess.call(shlex.split("/path/to/cmd --with --many args -p password"))`